# custom 'add' view animation to uistackview

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uikit, uistackview

[image: uistackview animations]

I'm playing with iOS9 uistackview and having problems to customize animation when adding element. You can notice that the yellow element position is being animated from top-left corner and starting with zero width.

I would like yellow element already being positioned below violet element and animate only height from 0 to some value (inverse behavior of green element animation)

I know its easy to do it when element is already in arrangeViews hierarchy unfortunately in my project I have to add and remove items dynamically at arbitrary index. Code below:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSLayoutConstraint* heightConstraint2;
    UIStackView *stackView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //View 1
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = true;
    [view1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:300].active = true;


    //View 2
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//    [view2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:70].active = true;
    heightConstraint2 = [view2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100];
    heightConstraint2.active = true;

    //View 3
    UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    [view3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:180].active = true;

    //Stack View
    stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];


    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    stackView.spacing = 0;


    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view1];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view2];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view3];

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.view addSubview:stackView];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    heightConstraint2.constant = 0;

    UIView *view4 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view4.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [view4.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:80].active = true;
    [view4.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:180].active = true;
    NSLayoutConstraint* heightConstraint4 = [view4.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
    [stackView insertArrangedSubview:view4 atIndex:3];
//    [stackView layoutIfNeeded];


    heightConstraint2.constant = 0;
    heightConstraint4.constant = 80;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:3
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [stackView layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Even though I don't know how to do that,but it's like table view and collection view,maybe there is a flow layout for it, I guessed.

Answer (score 2):

Add your view but set it as `hidden`, Then in animationBlock, set `hidden = true`

Comment: in block it is hidden = false.